# Codemirror editor set multiple line value

Tags: python, django, codemirror

Here is code to create codemirror object

```
var myCodeMirror = CodeMirror(document.getElementById('text_area'), {
  mode:  "text/x-c++src",
  lineNumbers: true,
  indentUnit: 4,
});
```

After I submit code, I get the code but I also want it to retain it in code editor after post,
This doesn't work when code is of multiple lines

```
myCodeMirror.setValue("{{submitted_code}}")
```

How to use multiline for codemirror editor?

Edit:

Here is necessary template code

```
<script>
    function codeGetter()
      {
        document.getElementById("user_code").value = myCodeMirror.getValue()
      }
</script>

{% load static %}

<script src="{% static 'codemirror.js' %}"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'codemirror.css' %}">
<script src="{% static 'clike.js' %}"></script>


<form action = "{%  url 'round2:handle_answer' user_id selected_question.pk   %}" method = "post" onclick=codeGetter()>

    {% csrf_token %}

    <div id="code_editor" name = "code_editor" style="margin-bottom: 0px; font-weight: bold;">Code Editor</div>

    <div id="text_area" name="text_area" style="margin-top: 0px;" ></div>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" id="submit" style="margin-left:75%" >

    <textarea id="user_code" name="user_code"></textarea>

</form>
```

Comment: What is {{submitted_code}} ?? Many things are unexplained in your code.What is myCodeMirror.getValue() ??

Comment: The code from code_editor div gets copied to to user_code. Then i get code from post method and then again render the same page which should retain the previous code which is in submitted_code

Answer (score 0):

It can be done as follows:

```
var html = `{{submitted_code}}`;

editor.setValue(html);
```

Using Multiline String: ``